# Add Scaffold and Area Option in Visual Studio 2013 Express

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

In my Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web, I don't see the `Add Scaffold` and `Area` options illustrated in http://www.itorian.com/2013/10/area-in-mvc-5-with-example-step-by-step.html.

Does this option exist in VS 2013 Express?  Do I need to install something to make it shown?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, I have scaffold option in my VS 13 express. Try to update to latest update 2.

Comment: @Gupta, thanks for your suggestion.  I updated but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an MVC 5 project you can right click on any folder and select new scaffolded Item... -> Then select Area under Common > MVC.

If you are using an MVC4 project in VS 2013 you have to right click on the project name and then select Add -> Area